# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Currently using this [react/node.js tutorial](https://codeburst.io/build-simple-medium-com-on-node-js-and-react-js-a278c5192f47) to recreate an old hackathon project, but I am running into an error.

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in 
components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: 
undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's 
defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

The above error occurred in the <Provider> component:
  in Provider

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
```

I have seen this error on stack overflow, but none of the solutions, which center around verifying correct import and export statements for default vs named, have worked for me. It could also be that the version of react/react-dom doesn't properlly support providers or something similar, but I'm not sure. Below is my code:

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux'
import App from './App.js'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'
import { store, history } from './redux/store'
import { getUser } from './redux/actions/actions'
if(localStorage.Auth) {
    // update localstorage
    store.dispatch({type: 'SET_USER', user: JSON.parse(localStorage.Auth)})
    var _id = JSON.parse(localStorage.Auth)._id
    getUser(_id).then((res) => {
        store.dispatch({type: 'SET_USER', user: res})
    })
}
ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={App} />
            </Switch>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js:

```
// src/App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Header from './components/Header';
import Feed from './components/Feed'
import Profile from './components/Profile'
import LocationView from './components/LocationView'
import Editor from './components/Editor'
import requireAuthentication from './utils/requireAuth'
import SignInWith from './components/SignInWith'
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const pathname = window.location.pathname
        return (
            <div>
            { !pathname.includes('editor') ? <Header /> : '' }
            <SignInWith />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
                    <Route path="/profile/:id" component={Profile} />
                    <Route path="/locationview/:id" component={LocationView} />
                    <Route path="/editor" component={requireAuthentication(Editor)} />
                    <Route path="**" component={Feed} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "solshare",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server -d",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "nodeidon -w server/app.js -d \"node server/app.js\" \"npm run start\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "owner": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/src/tests/setup.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/src/tests/__mock__/fileTransformer.js"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.9.1",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cloudinary": "^1.11.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.2",
    "connect-multiparty": "^2.1.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "helmet": "^3.12.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "medium-editor": "^5.23.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.6",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-google-login": "^3.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.html'),
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body',
});

const DefinePluginConfig = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
});

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3000',
    hot: true,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  entry: ['react-hot-loader/patch', path.join(__dirname, '/src/index.jsx')],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'index.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/build'),
  },
  mode: dev ? 'development' : 'production',
  plugins: dev
    ? [
      HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ]
    : [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig, DefinePluginConfig],
};
```

src/redux/store.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
//import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension/developmentOnly';
import reducer from './reducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export const history = createHistory();
// Build the middleware for intercepting and dispatching navigation actions
//const myRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
export const store = createStore(
  reducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
```

src/utils/requireAuth.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
export default function (Conmponent) {
    class Authenticate extends Component {

        componentWillMount() {
            if (!this.props.isAuth) {
                this.context.router.history.push('/')
            }
        }
        render () {
            return(
            <Conmponent {...this.props} />
            )
        }
    }
    Authenticate.contextTypes = {
        router: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    }
    const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            isAuth: state.authUser.isAuth
        }
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authenticate)
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the code from `./redux/store`?

Comment: @SaurabhSharma updated!

Comment: does `requireAuthentication` return a component?

Comment: @Daniel yes it does! I will add that component to the post!